# deleting contents of a label - Objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, crash, label

I have a label which stores any data that is entered. it has a property and has been synthesized.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *memoryDisplay;

@synthesize memoryDisplay;



-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
view.hidden = YES;

}
```

The label is in a view which is hidden on load

The view has a property and has been synthesized

on the same view there is a button for clearing a label

It has an Action

.h

```
- (IBAction)clearMemory:(id)sender;
```

And

.m

```
- (IBAction)clearMemory:(id)sender 
{

      self.memoryDisplay.text = @"";  

}
```

However, when ever I try to run the app it crashes and gives me this error

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key clearMemory.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13bc052 0x154dd0a 0x13bbf11 0x9b3032 0x924f7b 0x924eeb 0x93fd60 0x23291a 0x13bde1a 0x1327821 0x23146e 0xd8e2c 0xd93a9 0xd95cb 0x39a73 0x39ce2 0x39ea8 0x40d9a 0x11be6 0x128a6 0x21743 0x221f8 0x15aa9 0x12a6fa9 0x13901c5 0x12f5022 0x12f390a 0x12f2db4 0x12f2ccb 0x122a7 0x13a9b 0x1b28 0x1a85)
terminate called throwing an exceptionsharedlibrary apply-load-rules all

I also tried to add some if statements to check for possible problems:

```
- (IBAction)clearMemory:(id)sender 
{
if (!view.hidden) {
    if ([memoryDisplay.text length] > 1)
    {
      self.memoryDisplay.text = @"";  
    }

}
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem might be?

If I take off everything got to do with the clear button it all works perfectly.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Check all IB outlet bindings for broken links

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your memoryDisplay property is connected from the viewController to the UILabel in the nib/xib.

Comment: thanks for replying, yes It has been connected to the ViewController and also been synthesized.

Comment: yes, but has it been connected from the ViewController to the UILabel?  It is clear from your other responses that the UILabel is connected from the UILabel to the ViewController and connected to the IBAction method.

Comment: Yes the view controller is connected to the label, afaik that is the only way to do since if I ctrl click the label and drag to the view controller it doesn't give me the option to connect it to anything.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't do it the way I wanted, however I did find a workaround.

I placed a hidden, uneditable text box in the view which was empty and set the labels text to the text box whenever the clear button was pressed.